# Unable to install lime on windows 7

Tags: haxe, haxelib

I have Haxe Compiler version 2.10 and Haxe Library Manager 1.03. I have downloaded lime-1,0,1.zip and placed it on the haxe installation folder. Then running `haxelib local lime-1,0,1.zip` 
it is showing

`C:\>haxelib local lime-1,0,1.zip
Unknown command local
Haxe Library Manager 1.03 - (c)2006 Motion-Twin
 Usage : haxelib [command] [options]
 Commands :
  install : install a given library
  list : list all installed libraries
  upgrade : upgrade all installed libraries
  remove : remove a given library/version
  set : set the current version for a library
  search : list libraries matching a word
  info : list informations on a given library
  user : list informations on a given user
  register : register a new user
  submit : submit or update a library package
  setup : set the haxelib repository path
  config : print the repository path
  path : give paths to libraries
  run : run the specified library with parameters
  test : install the specified package localy
  dev : set the development directory for a given library
  git : uses git repository as library`

What wrong I am doing?

Comment: Where did you get the command `haxelib local lime-1,0,1.zip`? The error message is telling you that `local` is not a valid thing to type after `haxelib`. Your choices are `install`, `list`,...

Comment: I am following the instruction from [https://github.com/openfl/openfl/wiki/1.2.-Install-Lime](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/wiki/1.2.-Install-Lime)    Actually I want to install NME and as a first step I found that I have to install lime. As I don't have admin privilege so I am choosing manual install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an old version of `haxelib`, and of `haxe` as well. You should update to the latest Haxe version, which will also update haxelib to version 3.1.0-rc.4